How to Use Nextjs Middleware Matcher Redirect Users
I want to redirect users in my nextjs middleware matcher from "admin" to "login" page, however the redirect doesn't work, i try to match the url with the "/admin" for example "www.mydomain.com/admin" and redirect to "www.mydomain.com/login" but it doesn't work:

export function middleware(request) {
  // Middleware logic here
  const url = request.nextUrl.clone();

  // Example: Redirect if path is `/admin`
  if (url === '/admin') {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url));
  }

  return NextResponse.next(); // Continue to the requested page
}

// Configure the matcher to only run middleware on specific paths
export const config = {
  matcher: ['/admin', '/dashboard/:path*'], // Specify exact paths or patterns
};



Note that i've removed other things like auth and checking user authenticated or not and decide if to redirect or not if it's guest.

I've looked online for code examples, asked a college that i work with and try to read blogs about nextjs.

try to match the url base on the pathname of the url rather the entire url.
  if (url.pathname === '/admin') {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url));
  }

also, i'll refer you to nextjs docs about middleware watcher to look for github code examples of nextjs middleware watcher. good luck
